# Select multiple elements with different filterings

Tags: lists, filter, select, edit

**Summary:**

The problem is not on the filters, but on the selected entities list. The user need to do; filtering, then selection, then do another filtering saving the previous selection.

There is an alternative to show two lists, one with selected elements and the other with all elements? (see images)

---

This is a complex problem, let me try to explain and give as much info as I can.

**Context: platform and users**

I'm working (as a one man army UX) on an **existing platform** that moves millions of € every month. So changes need to be made very carefully.

Users manage **one kind of entity**, every entity has a detail view with a **lot of data**. Some data is sensitive, like taxes (affect payments), but an entity could have it blank while others don't.

Right now we **need** to improve the way they edit that entities, giving the user the ability to **edit many at the same time**.

We didn't have it until now because it's dangerous to change many at the same time, but we were **blocked** by an important client so we need to hurry and add this functionality (think of it as a block by google if you live on adwords)

**The need: interface changes**

The logical place to add this multiple selection is in the "***entity list***", where user manage their entities by **filtering and editing individually** (big users manage thousands)

**demanded flow** (by users and bosses):

- filtering
- select some elements
- more filtering
- more selection, adding this second to the saved previous selection
- click action1 or action2 button (goes to another screen with selected entities list and the field of the elements to change)

**elements to add**:

- checkboxes for entity selection
- "select all" checkbox (something like gmail selection)
- an additional list to the entities list, with the selected elements
- 2 buttons with the main actions (there are two "edit all" options)
- an explanatory text about the importance and perils of the changes

Right now I have this

[image: what I have right now]

And My first approach is this (WIP)

[image: first design approach]

**There is an alternative to show two lists, one with selected elements and the other with all elements?**

They will probably accept bright ideas, but I don't have any right now.

Thanks in advance. Feel free to edit the description if it's not clear enough.

edited to emphasise in the real problem

Answer (score 1):

You can show previously selected filter attributes as I have mentioned in below image. If it is multiple selection checkbox, then show just selected checkbox as selected until the user clicks "reset" button.

**Here is updated example layout added with drop down show at top right corner.**

[image]

Comment: the problem doesn't lie in the filter or the attributes, but in the list of entities and the selection of that entities when you want to filter with another criteria, to select more elements saving the first filtering

Comment: When user clicks to select new filter cirteria then show previously selected filter attributes only not the entity list. When user finalize the things to filter show at that time list as per newly filtered attribute. There is no sense to save previous filtered attributes after selecting the new one.

Comment: If it is necessary to show the previously filtered attributes then make drop down having custom name under which all the selected attributes would fall.

Comment: Common case example: filter by location, type Paris, and select all entities (500) with "select all" checkbox, then filter by New York (the list with results change) plus by name, type "whatever", so you see entities in NY with "whatever" in their name, user then add only 10 results by selecting them manually with the checkboxes, then click the button to edit taxes for the selected 510 entities, after click you go to another screen (that's not the issue here), the issue is how to show both selections, the 500 and the 10, at the same time so the user sees what entities he is going to edit

Comment: @AdriaPerezPla practically it's not possible to show these much entities in one interface. Initially list all the entities but once the filter applied show the entities which match the filter criteria.

Comment: Ok, with the new image I understand better what you are proposing, instead of showing the items selected, you propose to show a list like a history of searches/filterings with selections, right?

Comment: yeah, it's not possible, that's why is driving me crazy, the list though is paginated

Comment: So don't think with all this listing instead follow the approach which I suggested if it is feasible to you. I suggested this because recently work in the project in which we also had the same problem and implemented the solution which I suggested you.

Comment: Yes, if you want to give user to filter based on previously selected attribute then you can give them but I don't find it useful because it would be very rare situation when user select the previously selected attribute. But if as per your project need it requires to store then go ahead, might be user get benefited to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51113/discussion-between-adria-perez-pla-and-jasmin-javia).